# vector-matrix multiplication upperbound

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Let $\mathbf{p} = (p_i)_{i=1}^n$ with $p_i > 0$ be a ($n\times 1$)-column vector and consider a symmetric ($n\times n$)-matrix $\mathbf{A} = [a_{ij}]$ with $a_{ii} = 0$ and $a_{ij} \in [0,1]$ for $i \neq j$. How the ratio of below can be (tightly) bounded?

$$ r = \frac{\mathbf{p}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{p}}{\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{e}},$$

where $\mathbf{e}$ is ($n\times 1$)-column vector of ones. Also, assume that $c <\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{e} < d$ for constants $c>d>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
e^TAe = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij},
$$
which is just the sum of the elements of $A$.
Then
$$
p^TAp = \sum_{i,j}p_ip_j a_{ij} \le ( \max_i p_i )^2(\sum_{ij}a_{ij},)
$$
which gives the upper bound
$$
\frac{ p^TAp}{e^TAe} \le (\max_i p_i)^2 .
$$
Analogously, we obtain the lower bound
$$
\frac{ p^TAp}{e^TAe} \ge (\min_i p_i)^2 .
$$
These arguments do not use symmetry of $A$ nor the condition $a_{ii}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This came to my mind but I was hopping to get some tighter bounds using the symmetric, zero-diagonal assumptions and the upper bound condition on $e^TAe > c$. For your answer, the equality holds when only one element of A is 1 and rest is zero. The condition of  $e^TAe > c$  (for relatively large values of c)  requires at least to have c non-zero element. Do you think it is possible to improve your solution using other assumptions? Your help would be greatly appreciated.